# Empty result when querying likes of friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find out if friends of a user have liked a page or not. Unfortunately when calling `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID` I get an empty array, when using the `access_token` of my app.

When using the `access_token` of the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), everything seems to be fine and I'm getting the data. I've checked the permissions in my privacy settings and they both have the friends_likes permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that users who are admins of the page don't have a like entry. Therefore you won't get a result when querying the likes of said user.